# PHP IntelliSense on Fedora, executable not found

Tags: php, linux, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have Visual Studio Code installed on Fedora V 36. Even though I've set the php executable in the setttings.json file I'm still getting

```
PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7.4.0 or higher and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting
```

settings.json

```
{
    "php.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php",
}
```

`whereis php` shows

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib64/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

`php -v` shows

```
PHP 8.0.24 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2022 15:32:34) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.24, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

The question is, how can I get VS Code, or rather IntelliSense, to recognize the php executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that VsCode was having a permission issue with the php executable, due to VsCode being installed from Flatpak.

After some trial and error I ended up uninstalling the Flatpak version of VsCode and re-installing with directions from the official site.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_rhel-fedora-and-centos-based-distributions